# Shared FTP directory

Tags: unix, ftp

I have created /var/www directory on my machine. There works proftpd server. I also created 2 user and each of them has /var/www set as home directory. Both of them are in ftp-users group.  Files' owner is ftp-users group. How to set up everything, to allow both of them edit data in /var/www? By now, I managed to configure in such way, that they can edit files, but only created by their own.

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Make the group owner of /var/www be ftp-users.  make /var/www be `chmod g+s` (perhaps recursively).  This g+s will ensure that new directories or files created under /var/www will inherit the group ownership.  Then have proftpd use 002 as a umask (at least for these users).  Using 002 instead of the default 022 will ensure that new files/directories created are g+w (instead of just g+r).